Help identify an animated movie about fish?
So I saw this movie on TV around 15 years ago. It played during the middle of the day on a regular channel in Hungary, not one of the dedicated cartoon channels. This also makes me assume it's a movie, not a series. No idea which country may have been the source, it was most likely European, possibly Japanese (old-school anime style), but in general the kind of animation style you'd see in the 90s from studios with a passable budget.
The scene I remember showed a helicopter dropping boxes of some kind of poison or toxic waste into the ocean, and the animals tried to stop them. The fish did not look very cartoony, excluding the emphasized eyes and mouths, and I do recall at least one of them talking. 
Where it gets weird: the movie actually had gore in it, and was fairly dark in general. First some flying fish tried to stop the helicopter by flying into its rotor, but that just got them all chopped up into bloody chunks. A couple of sharks ate the boxes dropped into the ocean to stop the spread of the poison, and they all turned sickly green and stopped moving. Finally, this one box had a leak in it, and a little fish said goodbye to their bigger friend/relative before plugging the hole with their own body, stopping the leak and dying in the process.
Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

wish I knew but certainly sounds interesting, peaked my curiosity

I'm also trying to find the name of the movie. It aired in Serbia some 20 years ago. One more scene is in my memory: fish are trying to wake up the sea monster (looks similar to Loch Ness monster) which is asleep for a long time (maybe centuries) by swimming into its mouth and feeding it in that way, sacrificing themselves in order to make it help them to save the ocean.
I hope we will find the answer, somebody has to remember.
